# What exactly is "Binary Form"?

Tags: licensing, binary

I am asking in the context of the licenses on code that one sees all over the place.  Typically, they say something along the lines of "if you release a product containing this in binary form, it must contain X, Y, and Z."

Does that mean that if I use the code in an app, the app has to have a screen somewhere that contains X, Y, and Z in human-readable form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text is indicating that you must include X, Y, and Z if you distribute the compiled form of the code (as opposed to the source code). Assuming that X, Y, and Z are, for example, copyright notices, they would generally need to be included in documentation and other human-readable materials distributed along with the binaries.

Answer (score 1):

It's referring to if you use the library in its compiled form.  Binary is what gets run by the actual processor; i.e. code gets compiled to machine code for your processor at one point or another.

Comment: OK, but then do X, Y, and Z need to go into my SOURCE, or do they need to be readable by any USER or the project?

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly is “Binary Form”?

- **In laymans' term**, "Binary Form" is encoded form that is only understood by machine (*or any other special program made to read it - eg: docx file*).
- **For more details there's [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file).**

> Does that mean that if I use the code in an app, the app has to have a screen somewhere that contains X, Y, and Z in human-readable form?

- **Yes**, i.e. you should follow what the line says: *"if you release a product containing this in binary form, it must contain X, Y, and Z."*

Comment: docx is a zip :p